# Codeigniter - exec ffmpeg (win 8.1 with xampp)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ffmpeg, exec

i want to merge some image files (jpeg,png) to a short stop motion video clip.

The User can upload the images and the webapp will do a short movie... Thats the plan.

I have tried some variations i found in www -> exec, shell_exec

The ffmpeg.exe is in my root Folder (xampp/htdocs/xxx/ffmpeg.exe)

I put a function in my controller to do the clip.

```
public function render() {

    // Save the Session ID into the variable sessionId
    $sessionId = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
    // Path to the Userimage-Folder 
    $image_path = "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\uploads\$sessionId";

    $command = "C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\ffmpeg -framerate 1/5 -i".$image_path."/img_%03d.JPG -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4";

    exec($command);

}
```

The images are already in the same format and have a consecutive numbering.

I'am still a beginner, so please help me.

regards :)

Comment: After much research and try and error, i found the solution!!!! There were errors with the path. Now it works and i'am happy! :)